# Why does "Debut" represent the date they played their first match?

Tags: meaning

In football, DoB stands for "**D**ate of **B**irth", which is easy to understand.

On the other hand, "Debut" represent the date they played their first match, why is that? Is that a combination of first letters of some other words? What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Debut" is a noun [that means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debut):

> The occasion when someone performs or presents something to the public for the first time.

It comes from the French word "début" with the same meaning (and also used more generally with the sense of "beginning").

Acronyms are usually capitalized in English. An acronym like "Date Entry Bout Undoubtedly Transpired" (I just made this up, it's not a real thing!) would usually be written "DEBUT." When in doubt, a dictionary is your friend.

If you meant to suggest "DoB" and "debut" might have some connection due to the common D and B, the answer is a firm no. The fact that two words have a few letters in common is not an indication of similar meaning or common origin. This is no less true with acronyms.