# What does "no less true" mean?

Tags: meaning

An answer post to [Why does "Debut" represent the date they played their first match?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239853/109190) says

> If you meant to suggest "DoB" and "debut" might have some connection due to the common D and B, the answer is a firm no. The fact that two words have a few letters in common is not an indication of similar meaning or common origin. This is **no less true** with acronyms.

I googled this phrase and got

> "no less true" means the same thing as "not any less true".

which does not even give a bit more information.

So, what does "no less true" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No less" is equivalent to "the same amount or more." The sentence can be understood as:

> This is just as true with acronyms.

Or simply:

> This is also true with acronyms.

Comment: Thank you. Is it similar to "This is true with acronyms"?

Comment: Of course it is. Adding words like _also_ doesn't change the meaning.